# catkin build fail

Tags: ros, catkin, build

[image: Rosanswers logo]

sir
I tried to build the package which is created at desktop workspace. i follow the following commands

1. mkdir -p /home/chhonkar/Desktop/imagews/src
2. cd /home/chhonkar/Desktop/imagews/src/
3. catkin_create_pkg pack1  roscpp std_msgs rospy
4. cd .. (reached to /home/chhonkar/Desktop/imagews)
5. catkin_make

But this create problem. build process is not successful. i got some error. here i am copy few part of error.

```
RuntimeError: Multiple packages found with the same name "ardrone_autonomy":
- ardrone_autonomy
- share/ardrone_autonomy
CMake Error at /opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/safe_execute_process.cmake:11 (message):
  
  execute_process(/home/chhonkar/Desktop/imageproc/build/catkin_generated/env_cached.sh
  "/usr/bin/python" "/usr/bin/empy" "--raw-errors" "-F"
  "/home/chhonkar/Desktop/imageproc/build/catkin_generated/order_packages.py"
  "-o"
  "/home/chhonkar/Desktop/imageproc/build/catkin_generated/order_packages.cmake"
  "/opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/em/order_packages.cmake.em") returned
  error code 1
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/em_expand.cmake:25 (safe_execute_process)
  /opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_workspace.cmake:29 (em_expand)
  CMakeLists.txt:63 (catkin_workspace)
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/chhonkar/Desktop/imageproc/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/chhonkar/Desktop/imageproc/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/197356/catkin-build-fail./) by [ASHISH CHHONKAR](https://answers.ros.org/users/20131/ashish-chhonkar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2014-11-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2014-11-13**:
Did you [create workspace](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/create_a_workspace) before creating package ?

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2014-11-13**:
The error message indicates that you have multiple packages with the same name in your source space. Can you please post the recursive content under your workspace folder: /home/chhonkar/Desktop/imagews/src

**Comment by [ASHISH CHHONKAR](https://answers.ros.org/users/20131/ashish-chhonkar/) on 2014-11-13**:
@bvbdort yes i created the workspace of name imagews......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem is that you have two copies of the package ardrone_autonomy in your system. Remove one of them.

If you don't need that package you can do:

```
sudo apt-get remove ros-indigo-ardrone-autonomy
```

Then try to run catkin_make again.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) with karma: 5625 on 2014-11-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ASHISH CHHONKAR](https://answers.ros.org/users/20131/ashish-chhonkar/) on 2014-11-14**:
whenever i open a new terminal following bash come in start... is this affect the system, because previously it not come.

*
bash: source/home/chhonkar/Desktop/imagews/devel/setup.bash: No such file or directory
chhonkar@chhonkar-pc:~$
*

**Comment by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) on 2014-11-16**:
You will probably need to rebuild the workspace in /home/chhonkar/Desktop/imagews

**Comment by [ASHISH CHHONKAR](https://answers.ros.org/users/20131/ashish-chhonkar/) on 2014-11-17**:
@Martin thanks for your response..... i resolved the problem. above problem of bash has been solved my removing all paths from bashrc file except opt/ros/indigo....